# Structure issue using C

Tags: c

I'm trying to store strings into dynamical allocated memory. I'm able to break the strings down and store them within the members of the struct and print them perfectly within the function `readFile`, but when it comes to printing it in main, it's only printing the last scan and everything else is `null`. I'm thinking that maybe I'm not allocating the array of structures correctly. Here's my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <crtdbg.h>  // needed to check for memory leaks (Windows only!)
#endif

#define MEM_ERROR printf("Not enough memory\n")
#define FLUSH while( getchar() != '\n' )

typedef struct
{
char id[5];
char *name;
int *sales;
int total;
int low;
int high;
}PERSON;

typedef struct
{
int worker;
int weeks;
PERSON *pAry;
}HEADER;

//  Function Declaration
void    valiFile(char nameIn[]);
FILE*   openFile(char nameIn[]);
void    getHeader(FILE* fpFile, HEADER *pHead);
PERSON* aloPerson(int workers);
void    readFile(FILE* fpFile, HEADER *pHead);
char*   aloName(HEADER *pHead, int strCount);
void    repeat(char nameIn[]);


int main ( void )
{
//  Local Declaration
FILE* fpFile;
char  nameIn[25];
char *endPro = "end";
HEADER *pHead = (HEADER*)calloc(1, sizeof(HEADER));

//  Statement
printf("Please select file to to open.\nsales or sales_2: ");
scanf("%s", nameIn);
FLUSH;

do
{
    valiFile(nameIn);
    fpFile = openFile(nameIn);
    getHeader(fpFile, pHead);
    readFile(fpFile, pHead);

    //printf("%s\n", pHead->pAry[0].id);

    //free(pHead);

    repeat(nameIn);
}

return 0;
}// main

/* ========== valiFile ==========

========== */
void valiFile(char nameIn[])
{
//  Local Declaration
char *file = "sales";
char *file2 = "sales_2";
int i;
int check = 0;

//  Statement
do
{
    for(i = 0; nameIn[i]; i++)
    {
        nameIn[i] = tolower(nameIn[i]);
    }

    if(strcmp(file, nameIn) != 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(file2, nameIn) != 0)
        {
            printf("\nPlease enter a valid file.\n");
            printf("sales or sales_2: ");
            scanf("%s", nameIn);
            FLUSH;
        }
        else
            check = 1;
    }
    else
        check = 1;
}
while(check != 1)
;

return;
}// valiFile

/* ========== openFile ==========

========== */
FILE* openFile(char nameIn[])
{
//  Local Declaration
FILE* fpFile;
char *strSale = "sales";

//  Statement
if(strcmp(strSale, nameIn) == 0)
{
    fpFile = fopen("sales.txt", "r");
    if(fpFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("File didn't read correcty.\n");
        exit(100);
    }
}
else
{
    fpFile = fopen("sales_2.txt", "r");
    if(fpFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("File didn't read correcty.\n");
        exit(100);
    }
}

return fpFile;
}// openFile

/* ========================= getHeader ========================

============================================================*/
void getHeader(FILE* fpFile, HEADER *pHead)
{
//  Local Declaration
int worker, salesWeek, i;
PERSON *list;

//  Statement
fscanf(fpFile, "%d %d", &worker, &salesWeek);
list = aloPerson(worker);
HEADER header = {worker, salesWeek, list};
*pHead = header;

return;
}// getHeader

/* aloPerson

*/
PERSON* aloPerson(int worker)
{
//  Local Declaration
PERSON *list;

//  Statement
list =(PERSON*)calloc(worker, sizeof(PERSON));
if(list == NULL)
{
    MEM_ERROR, exit(103);
}

return list;
}// aloPerson

/* readFile

*/
void readFile(FILE* fpFile, HEADER *pHead)
{
//  Local Declaration
char temp[50];
int strCount = 0;
char *loc;
char *ptr;
int i;

//  Statement
fscanf(fpFile, "%*d %*d");
for(i = 0; i < pHead->worker; i++)
{
    while(fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), fpFile))
    {
        ptr = temp;
        loc = strchr(temp, ' ');
        strncpy(pHead->pAry[i].id, temp, (loc - ptr));
        ptr += (loc - temp);
        *ptr++;
        loc = strchr(temp, ';');
        strCount = (loc - ptr);

        pHead->pAry[i].name = aloName(pHead, strCount);

        strncpy(pHead->pAry[i].name, ptr, (loc - ptr));
        ptr += (loc - ptr);
        printf("%s\n", pHead->pAry[i].name);
    }
}


return;
}// readFile

/* aloName

*/
char* aloName(HEADER *pHead, int strCount)
{
//  Local Declaration
char *names;

//  Statement;
names = malloc((strCount + 1)*sizeof(char));

return names;
}
```

Comment: Enable all warnings & debugging information from your compiler (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux). Then learn to use the debugger (`gdb` on Linux) and perhaps some memory leak detector (`valgrind` on Linux). Also, please indent your code, and show a minimal example.

Comment: And please don't attempt to re-invent the C language with obscure macros. It makes your code less clear, less readable and harder to debug as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how to turn on all my warnings. Teacher never really went over how to do this on our IDE, but I actually solved what was wrong.

Comment: Do explain your solution by answering your own question. It may help others.